# SwiftUI Localization Issue

Tags: swiftui, localization, localizable.strings, swiftui-text

I have a project with two targets representing two different final products. Until now the localization was shared between the two targets, but now I have just one string to be localized differently according to the active target. In order to avoid duplicating the *Localizable.string* file ad tweak the file target membership, I decided to create two different *Localizable-Ext.string* files containing just the string to be translated differently for each target.

I'm using the SwiftUI `Text` initializer accepting a `LocalizedStringKey` parameter which automatically looks up the corresponding translation inside the file. This is what has to be done in most cases. I noticed that this initializer also accepts a `tableName` parameter corresponding to the .string filename where the match should be taken.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a custom `Text` initializer which takes the string key, looks up for it inside the default *Localizable.string* file and, if no match is found, falls back to the right file extension (string table) and search for it there. Apparently this is tough to achieve since I cannot manage to get the key value from the `LocalizedStringKey` instance.

Comment: You will have to create your own

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like

```
extension Text {
    public init<S>(looking text: S) where S : StringProtocol {
        let text = String(text)
        var translated = NSLocalizedString(text, comment: "")

        // returns same if no translation, so ...
        if translated == text {
            // ... continue in other table
            translated = NSLocalizedString(text, tableName: "Localizable-Ext",
                bundle: .main, value: text, comment: "")
        }
        // already translated, so avoid search again
        self.init(verbatim: translated)
    }
}
```